# Perl align text (left, center, right) without packages

Tags: regex, perl, alignment

I wrote this short subroutine to left,center,right-align a multiline string.

How can I make it better ? (shorter, prettier, optimized)? Can you offer some suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

# A bit of text
$_ = <<END;
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
          Curabitur pretium odio dictum nisl posuere, vitae mollis nibh facilisis
   Curabitur tempus tincidunt ante eget facilisis
     Pellentesque ut accumsan dui, nec semper odio
        Ut libero lacus, fermentum quis ultricies quis, tempus nec augue
                   Mauris tincidunt hendrerit accumsan
END

# Test each alignment case
for my $align ('left', 'center', 'right') {
    print align($_, $align)."\n";
}

# Alignment subroutine
sub align {
    my ($_, $align) = @_;    # Text to align, Alignment type
    my $re = qw/^([^\n]*)$/; # A regex to match each line
    s/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$//gm;   # Remove trailing/leading spaces

    # Get longest line
    my $max = 0;
    $max = length($1) > $max ? length($1) : $max while /$re/gm;

    # Do the alignment
    s|$re|$1 . " " x ($max-length($1))|mge if $align eq 'left';
    s|$re|" " x (($max-length($1))/2) . $1|mge if $align eq 'center';
    s|$re|" " x ($max-length($1)) . $1|mge if $align eq 'right';

    return $_;
}
```

I am such a beginner with Perl and I am sure I am missing that genious that will make my code magic.

Some suggestions?

Comment: not better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: One comment: You're calculating by the longest line, what can cause problems aligning some subsequent blocks. Maybe one more (optional) parameter (wanted_line_length) could address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's clearest to split the string into lines and process them in a loop.

Like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub max;

my $text = <<END_TEXT;
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
        Curabitur pretium odio dictum nisl posuere, vitae mollis nibh facilisis
 Curabitur tempus tincidunt ante eget facilisis
   Pellentesque ut accumsan dui, nec semper odio
      Ut libero lacus, fermentum quis ultricies quis, tempus nec augue
                 Mauris tincidunt hendrerit accumsan
END_TEXT

for my $align (qw/ left right centre /) {
  print align($text, $align), "\n";
}

sub align {

   state %core;
   @core{qw/ left centre center right /} = (0, 1, 1, 2) unless %core;

   my @lines = split m{$/}, shift;
   s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g for @lines;

   my @indices = (1, 2);
   splice @indices, $core{lc shift}, 0, 0;

   my $max = max map length, @lines;

   return join '', map {

      my $padlen = $max - length;
      my $pad1   = ' ' x $padlen;
      my $pad2   = substr($pad1, 0, $padlen/2, '');

      join '', ($_, $pad1, $pad2)[@indices], "\n";

   } @lines;
}


sub max {
  my $max = shift;
  $_ > $max and $max = $_ for @_;
  $max;
}
```

Comment: @mpapec: You wrote no comment on your edit of my answer. Can you give me a reason not to roll it back?

Comment: Explicit returns, and less obscure map returns; thought it is self evident.

Comment: @mpapec: Does that make you happier?!

Comment: It is your code. One good argument for explicit return is not to scroll down the block of code just to see that this is the last statement in subroutine.

Comment: `state` doesn't work with my version of Perl but this example is wonderful. I've learned lot of new things, thanks

Comment: @coin: I'm glad you like it. I wrote it with the intent of being interesting, rather than being what I would code in a live program. Do you understand it? I thought mapping the alignments to lists of indices may be a little obscure! All that will happen if you change `state` to `my` is that the hash will be set up on every call rather than just the first. Just move the `my %core` declaration outside the subroutine and all will be well. Sounds like you should update your Perl though: you must be on version 8 or earlier, which is at least six years old!

Answer (score 4):

Some minor modifications; newer perl gives warning when using `$_` as lexical (my) variable, simpler `$re` and properly compiled (`qr` vs `qw`), removed unneeded ternary assignment, added `elsif` to skip some conditions.

```
sub align {
    local $_ = shift;
    my ($align) = @_;    # Text to align, Alignment type
    my $re = qr/^(.*)/m;
    s/^\h+|\h+$//gm;   # Remove trailing/leading spaces

    # Get longest line
    my $max = 0;
    length($1) > $max and $max = length($1) while /$re/g;

    if    ($align eq 'left')   { s|$re|$1 . " " x ($max-length($1))|ge }
    elsif ($align eq 'center') { s|$re|" " x (($max-length($1))/2) . $1|ge }
    elsif ($align eq 'right')  { s|$re|" " x ($max-length($1)) . $1|ge }

    return $_;
}
```

Tempted to use anon hashref instead `elsif`, but that would not contribute to readability,

```
{
  left   => sub { s|$re|$1 . " " x ($max-length($1))|ge },
  center => sub { s|$re|" " x (($max-length($1))/2) . $1|ge },
  right  => sub { s|$re|" " x ($max-length($1)) . $1|ge },

}->{$align}->();
```

Comment: Nice tricks, I like the `local`...`shift` and the way you get the `$max`